# How to bulkify trigger when loading so many records records at a time?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have trigger which will create new Lead record when ever a record is inserted in the Custom object.

The issue is my trigger is working only when one record is inserted.
It is storing the same value for all the records when inserted in bulk.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Here is my Code :

```
trigger CreateLead on CustomObject__c (after insert) {

    List <Lead> leadToInsert = new List <Lead>();
    RecordType rt = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Lead' AND Name = 'RecordType Name' LIMIT 1];
    Set<String> CustomerInfoStore = new Set<String>();

    Set<ID> AccId = new Set<ID>();

    for (CustomObject__c HTC: Trigger.new) {  

        CustomerInfoStore.add(HTC.Code_Number__C);

    }    

    System.debug('Debug 1 string' + CustomerInfoStore  );


    List<Account> accList = [Select ID,Name,ACC_Code_Number__C,Assigned_pr__r.ID from Account Where ACC_Code_Number__C IN: CustomerInfoStore];

    if((accList.Size()>0)){

    for(Account acc : accList){
    AccId.add(acc.Assigned_pr__r.ID);

    }
    }

    List<Contact> conList= [Select ID,Name from Contact where AccountId IN:AccId AND iscontact = 'true'];



    System.debug('Debug 2 list : ' + accList);

    for (CustomObject__c HTC : Trigger.new) {

        //meets the criteria
        if (HTC.Name != Null) {  

        System.debug('Debug for For loop');


                Lead leadRec = new Lead (); //instantiate the object to put values for future record


                leadRec.RecordTypeID = rt.ID;
                leadRec.LastName = HTC.Last_Name__c; 
                leadRec.Company = HTC.Company_Name__c;
                leadRec.ProductFlyNameHTC__c = HTC.Product__c;
                  if(HTC.Code_Number__C != Null && (!accList.isEmpty()) && (accList.Size()>0))
                  {
                    leadRec.Account_Pr__c = accList[0].Assigned_pr__r.ID;

                    }

                    if(conList.Size() > 0){
                     leadRec.Account_Pr_Contact__c = conList[0].ID ;
                    }

                leadRec.Code_Number__C = HTC.Code_Number__C;
                leadRec.Budget_Value__c = HTC.Value__c;

                leadToInsert .add(leadRec );

                System.debug('Debug lead Rec' + leadToInsert);





        }//end if

    }//end for loop

    try {
        insert leadToInsert ; 
    } catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
        system.debug ('Error: Message' +e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue you're facing: catching and ignoring exceptions, seen here as just writing the error message to the debug log, is very poor practice. It would be better to not have the try/catch within the trigger at all and let the exception bubble up or use `sObject.addError('some message');` on the failing records. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following issues with your code.

1. This line will point to first record in list regardless number of trigger.new records

   ```
   leadRec.Account_Pr__c = accList[0].Assigned_pr__r.ID;
   ```
2. Same issue with Contact details

   ```
   leadRec.Account_Pr_Contact__c = conList[0].ID ;
   ```

So you need to get that data inside a map which will be used to get data on the basis of account id.

Please check following code with inline comments where I have added data in map which we are using inside trigger.new loop. I am assuming that a single contact exist for an account but if that is not the case you can take below code and write logic around it.

```
trigger CreateLead on CustomObject__c (after insert) {

    List <Lead> leadToInsert = new List <Lead>();
    RecordType rt = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Lead' AND Name = 'RecordType Name' LIMIT 1];
    Set<String> CustomerInfoStore = new Set<String>();

    Set<string> AccId = new Set<string>();

    for (CustomObject__c HTC: Trigger.new) {  

        CustomerInfoStore.add(HTC.Code_Number__C);

    }    

    System.debug('Debug 1 string' + CustomerInfoStore  );

    /*****************it will be map of Account.*****************/

    Map<id,Account> accList = new Map<id,Account>([Select ID,Name,ACC_Code_Number__C,Assigned_pr__r.ID from Account Where ACC_Code_Number__C IN: CustomerInfoStore]);

    /*if((accList.Size()>0)){

    for(Account acc : accList){
    AccId.add(acc.Assigned_pr__r.ID);

    }
    }*/

    //List<Contact> conList= [Select ID,Name from Contact where AccountId IN:AccId AND iscontact = 'true'];
    /************************ this will hold contact data. Assumption is you have single contact per account with that condition**************/
    Map<id,Contact> contact = new map<id,Contact>();
    for(Contact con : [Select ID,Name from Contact where AccountId IN:accList.keyset() AND iscontact = 'true'])
    {
        mapContact.put(con.accountid,con);
    }


    System.debug('Debug 2 list : ' + accList);

    for (CustomObject__c HTC : Trigger.new) {

        //meets the criteria
        if (HTC.Name != Null) {  

        System.debug('Debug for For loop');


                Lead leadRec = new Lead (); //instantiate the object to put values for future record


                leadRec.RecordTypeID = rt.ID;
                leadRec.LastName = HTC.Last_Name__c; 
                leadRec.Company = HTC.Company_Name__c;
                leadRec.ProductFlyNameHTC__c = HTC.Product__c;
                  if(HTC.Code_Number__C != Null )
                  {
                    /**************Get the data from map and fill the Acocunt details*******/
                    if(accList.containskey(HTC.Code_Number__C))
                    leadRec.Account_Pr__c = accMap.get(HTC.Code_Number__C).Assigned_pr__r.ID;

                    }

                    /**************Get the data from map and fill the contact details*******/
                    if(mapContact.containskey(HTC.Code_Number__C))
                    leadRec.Account_Pr_Contact__c = mapContact.get(HTC.Code_Number__C).ID;

                    }

                    /*if(conList.Size() > 0){
                     leadRec.Account_Pr_Contact__c = conList[0].ID ;
                    }*/

                leadRec.Code_Number__C = HTC.Code_Number__C;
                leadRec.Budget_Value__c = HTC.Value__c;

                leadToInsert .add(leadRec );

                System.debug('Debug lead Rec' + leadToInsert);





        }//end if

    }//end for loop

    try {
        insert leadToInsert ; 
    } catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
        system.debug ('Error: Message' +e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying  :)  I have one doubt AccountId IN:AccId  which one you are referring ?

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: @ Himanshu thanks for updating, Sorry to bug you  but I am getting exception like Apex trigger createLead caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: createLead: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: 1036713362 (code Number ): External entry point

Comment: it is because Set<ID> AccId = new Set<ID>(); accid is not Id, it is number in your case. check the updated answer for that line.

Comment: The error is gone Map<id,Account> accList  replaced with Map<String,Account> . But the value is not assigning to Lead field